Action film where a Chinese guy and a Black guy fight an army of super engineered fighters
Its an action film, where a Chinese dude and a black guy (who is american and a sassy gangster type of guy) fight an evil group of people who engineer super fighters with chips in their heads. There is a scene where they have a big fight in a quarry, and then at the end of the film, the Chinese guy fights the super engineerd bad guy who has a super chip and is way better than everyone else. He wins against the guy, and they run out of the building and it explodes. 
P.S It's not rush hour ;)

Sounds like the action movie Drive from 1997.

The protagonist of the film is Toby Wong (played by Mark Dacascos), Chinese man who had crossed the Pacific as a stowaway on a freighter. [...] he "borrows" a car and takes its owner, failed songwriter Malik Brody (played by Kadeem Harrison) as a hostage. Toby used to be secret Chinese agent with a revolutionary bio-chip implant which gave him superhuman strength and other abilities. Now he wants to get to Los Angeles and deliver the chip to rival corporations. As Toby and Malik drive to Los Angeles, they are pursued by hordes of mercenaries led by cruel Madison (played by John Piper-Ferguson).

It's an Asian-black pairing and ends precisely like you said. Here's the trailer:



